# Efficient way to search and sort data with elasticsearch as a datastore

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using elasticsearch as a primary data store to save data and our indexing strategy is time based(for example, we create an index every 6 hours - configurable). The search-sort queries that come to our application contain time range; and based on input time range we calculate the indices need to be used for searching data.

Now, if the input time range is large - let's say 6 months, and we delegate the search-sort query to elasticsearch then elasticsearch will load all the documents into memory which could drastically increase the heap size(we have a limitation on the heap size).

One way to deal with the above problem is to get the data index by index and sort the data in our application ; indices are opened/closed accordignly; for example, only latest 4 indices are opened all the time and remaining indices are opened/closed based on the need. I'm wondering if there is any better way to handle the problem in hand.

Comment: What is the amount of data you'll be storing (in both disk space and number of documents)? An index per 6 hours is probably overkill. We make an index every 24 hours and some get to about 120 GB in size with 100 million documents. What is your retention period? At least 6 months it seems. Also, opening and closing indices just to get some data should be a rarity, closing an index is like archiving it. There is a large overhead to reopen a closed index. We have 2 years of server stat data and never close those indices.

Comment: Our data size is almost same as yours and retention period is configurable. We need to open/close the old indices(older than one day) only when needed, otherwise, elasticsearch will load all the documents in to memory;especially when sorting the data.

Comment: As an aside. You might want to consider if Elasticsearch is reliable enough to be your primary data store. If you don't mind losing data sometimes then no worries. This blog post explains it's failure modes in detail https://aphyr.com/posts/323-call-me-maybe-elasticsearch-1-5-0 and Elasticsearch maintain a page about their ongoing work on fixing these issues https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html

Comment: How many results are you likely to need to sort?

Comment: Let's take an example: time range is 6 months, total indices need to be searched are 720, and the number of documents in a single  index are 100,000.

Comment: @Vanlightly filter comes into picture depending on the input query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE
Option 1
Instead of opening and closing indexes you could experiment with limiting the field data cache size.

You could limit the field data cache to a percentage of the JVM heap size or a specific size, for example 10Gb. Once field data is loaded into the cache it is not removed unless you specifically limit the cache size. Putting a limit will evict the oldest data in the cache and so avoid an OutOfMemoryException.

You might not get great performance but then it might not be worse than opening and closing indexes and would remove a lot of complexity.

Take into account that Elasticsearch loads all of the documents in the index when it performs a sort so that means whatever limit you put should be big enough to load that index into memory.

[See limiting field data cache size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html)

Option 2
Doc Values
This means writing necessary meta data to disk at index time, so that means the "fielddata" required for sorting lives on disk and not in memory. It is not a huge amount slower than using in memory fielddata and in fact can alleviate problems with garbage collection as less data is loaded into memory. There are some limitations such as string fields needing to be not_analyzed.

You could use a mixed approach and enable doc values on your older indexes and use faster and more flexible fielddata on current indexes (if you could classify your indexes in that way). That way you don't penalize the queries on "active" data.

[See Doc Values documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your assumption is correct; we do ingest large amounts of data in relatively small periods of time. But your answer didn't really answer my original  problem - memory consumption problem when sorting needs to be done.

Comment: Fair enough. I will post some more comments on the question so we can get some more information and I'll improve my response.

Comment: I have fully updated the answer to be relevant to sorting

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try both the options you have mentioned.